# Java Get/Set date program won't compile

Tags: java

The program is to take in day, month and year from the user then display them, using a separate class and separate methods to perform each get/set part as well as the display function.

It's not compiling, and I'm getting an error:

Date.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
Scanner Obj = new Scanner(System.in);
^
1 error

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner Obj = new Scanner(System.in);

public class Date{
  int month; //instance variables
  int day;
  int year;
  int m;
  int d;
  int y;
    
    
    public void date(int m, int d, int y){ //constructor
    int month = m;
    int day = d;
    int year = y;
    }
    
    
    public void getmonth(){
        System.out.print("Enter month: ");
        int month = Obj.nextInt();
    }
    
    public void setmonth(int m){
        month = m;
    }
    
    public void getday(){
        System.out.print("Enter day: ");
        int day = Obj.nextInt();
    }
    
    public void setday(int d){
        day = d;
    }
    
    public void getyear(){
        System.out.print("Enter year: ");
        int year = Obj.nextInt();
    }
    
    public void setyear(int y){
        year = y;
    }
    
    public void displaydate(){
        System.out.print(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
    
    }
    

    

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date myobj = new Date();
   
      
    Date myobj1 = new Date();
    Date myobj2 = new Date();
    Date myobj3 = new Date();
    Date myobj4 = new Date();
    Date myobj5 = new Date();
    Date myobj6 = new Date();
    Date myobj7 = new Date();  
      
      
    myobj1.getmonth();
    myobj2.setmonth();
    myobj3.getday();
    myobj4.setday();
    myobj5.getyear();
    myobj6.setyear();
    myobj7.displaydate();
     
      
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is outside of your class. That is not an appropriate place for a variable to be declared.

Move it into your class as a member or into a method as a local variable.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Date{
  int month; //instance variables
  int day;
  int year;
  int m;
  int d;
  int y;
  // consider calling it "obj" so it starts with a lowercase as per Java conventions
  Scanner Obj = new Scanner(Systsem.in); 

  // other methods below snipped for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable declaration should be inside class or method.